# MySQL Syntax Error - Individual queries run successfully, but together they fail

Tags: mysql

When trying to run the following query I get an "invalid syntax" error.

```
set @maxid = (select max(id) from Seat);

select case 
        when id % 2 = 0 then id-1 
        when id = @maxid then id
        else id+1 end as id, student from Seat
group by id, student
order by id
```

Full error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'select case
> when id % 2 = 0 then id-1
> when id = @maxid then id' at line 7

The odd part is if I run the `SET` statement by itself (without the `SELECT` statement) or the `SELECT` statement by itself (without the `SET` statement), they both execute successfully.

Comment: There's no need of a `GROUP BY` in your query, as there are no aggregation functions in the clauses of your second query, why are you using it? The `SUM` aggregation of the first query gets computed on all columns of the "*Seat*" table before your second query gets executed.  @SUMguy

Comment: Also why can you not include the first query as part of the second, there's no need for a separate variable.

Comment: How are you trying to run this query?

Comment: @lemon - I only added the group by as I thought not having it might be the cause of the syntax error, it obviously wasn't I just didn't delete

Comment: @stu - variable is for readability

Comment: Are you executing this from a programming language? Most APIs don't allow you to execute multiple queries in the same call, you have to do them with separate calls.

Comment: your code works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nBZKDSkVw4ViuJX88AzQ2G/1 @SUMGuy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can combine these into a single query by joining with a subquery that sets the variable.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN id % 2 == 0 THEN id - 1
        WHEN id = @maxid THEN id
        ELSE id + 1
    END AS id,
    student
FROM Seat
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @maxid := MAX(id) FROM Seat)
ORDER BY id
```